# Using metasearch's contains search option for non-string data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

While using metasearch gem to do a somewhat complex search I got an error when using the "_contains" option an numerical(decimal) field and later found out in the documentation that it in only works on string data type fields. Since metasearch doesn't work with virtual attributes I can't think of a way to achieve this .Are there any workarounds for this?
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Is there a way of creating a create a custom where with matches predicate? I haven't been able to format the param.

Comment: combining     ['equals', 'eq', {:validator => Proc.new {|param| !param.blank? || (param == false)}}],

    ['contains', 'like', 'matches', {:types => STRINGS, :predicate => :matches, :formatter => '"%#{param}%"'}],